# What is closed form solution (if there is any) to this PDE :

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations

What is the explicit solution to this PDE?

Before I write the equation let $P(t,n)=P(X(t)=n) $ where P is a probabilty function such that for every $t$ it satisfis
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(t,n) =1$.

X(t) is a stochastic process. For the purpose of this question it doesn't matter what $X$ is. I just wanted to tell where $P$ comes from!

The main question is as follows. Maybe you can skip previous statements and start from here!

Let $P: [0, \infty) \times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a nice function {Continuous derivatives,...} satisfying this partial differential equation with initial conditions:

$$\partial_{t} P(t,n)=aP(t,n-1)+b(n)P(t,n) \quad \quad \quad ;n\geq1$$
$$P(t,0)=r_{t}$$ 
$$ P(0,0)=1$$ and
$$     P(0,n)=0 \quad ;n\geq 1$$

Where $a$ is a constant and $b(n)$ is a functions which depends on $n$. I can give you $ b(n)$ or $r_{t}$ but they might be complicated functions so I believe we'd better write them in this form!

Can anyone find an explict (general ) solution of $P(t,n)$ in terms of $a$, $b(n)$, $r_{t}$  ?

Answer (score 0):

Given $P(t,n-1)$, you have a first-order linear initial value problem for $P(t,n)$, whose solution is
$$ P(t,n) = e^{b(n) t} \int_0^t a P(s,n-1) e^{-b(n) s} \; ds $$
In the absence of an explicit form for $P(t,0)$, there's not much hope of anything more explicit than this.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes I  thought in the same way.